# Windows Server 2003 on Virtualbox: Disk becomes unavailible after adding it as a cluster resource

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtualbox, cluster

I created a test cluster in Windows 2003 running on Virtual Box. The virtual disk to be used as a cluster resource has been changed to type **shereable** using VBoxManage command line utility. On that disk I created a primary partition and mounted it on one server as drive D. The cluster has been created successfully using Majority Node Set for quorum.

When adding drive D as a resource it failes and becomes unavailible in explorer, removing the disk from the resources makes it availible again.

To eliminate the Shereable vdi disk as the cause I created a new virtual disk on a new virtual SCSI controller, which does not have Shereable for it's Type. Still when added as a cluster resource it fails and becomes unavailible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last I checked, VirtualBox virtual disks are not supported for Cluster Services. You should use a third VM to present this disk as iSCSI rather than as a shared vdisk.

Comment: I think you're right, I'll implement it using ISCSI and FreeNAS, been looking into it as I read your answer. Thanks.

Comment: It also brings me to the thought that it's about time to ditch VirtualBox...

Comment: I assumed that this was in a test environment. I absolutely would not let VirtualBox anywhere near a production environment. Both ESXi and Hyper-V are free and work fine in smaller installations without the more expensive features from the paid add-ons.

Comment: It's a test environment, I agree with you on what you said about VirtualBox.